# Hi I'm getting an error when I type this:

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
\usepackage{geometry}                       % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                          % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                       % Activate for for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}          % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}               % Use pdf, png, jpg, or epsÂ§ with pdflatex; use eps in DVI mode                            % TeX will automatically convert eps --> pdf in pdflatex

\usepackage{array, multirow}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{amssymb}


\title{Measurement Homework 4}
\author{Mathilde Caurier}
\date{}                         % Activate to display a given date or no date

\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\section{}
%\subsection{}

\begin{tabular}{| >{\centering} m{6cm} | >{\centering} m{3cm} | >{\centering} m{3cm} |}
\hline  
\multirow{2}{6 cm}{ Unemployment rates} & \multicolumn{2} {|c|} {Gender} \\
\cline{2-3}  
       & Men & Women \\
\hline
Considering total population & 0 & 0 \\
Considering active population & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is the error?

Comment: Maybe the space in `\multirow{2}{6 cm}`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `! Misplaced \noalign.`. @ Caurier This is due to the `\centering` which redefines ``\\``. Either replace ``\\`` by `\tabularnewline` or use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}`

Comment: @clemens: You checked it? ;-) I was too lazy for that

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes. The MWE isn't bad and the error and the solution are clear :)